# Event using a generic type constraint to a delegate

Tags: c#, events, delegates, generic-type-parameters

I was trying to implement (in C#8.0) a class with a generic type parameter (constraint to a delegate) having an event parameter with the same generic type. The intended purpose is to have some custom event handling (Subscribe & Unsubscribe functions) while still allowing any kind of delegate associated with it.

```
public class AEvent<T> where T : Delegate
{
    private event T eventData;

    public AEvent() { }
}
```

Starting out with the code above, the IDE gives me this error:

> 'eventData': event must be of a delegate type

Can someone explain briefly why can't I implement this? Or if there's any alternative way of achieving this?

Comment: Ho do you expect to raise the event? Note that, for example `Action<T>`, `Action<T1, T2>`, `Action<T1, T2, T3>` ... all inherit from `Delegate`.

Comment: `Delegate` is not itself a delegate type, it's the base type for all delegates

Answer (score 2):

The C# specification *explicitly* states this is not allowed *(my bold)*

[**Events**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#events)

> The type of an event declaration **must** be a *delegate_type* ....

[**Delegates**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/delegates)

> The only way to declare a delegate type is via a *delegate_declaration*. A delegate type is a class type that **is derived from** `System.Delegate`. *...snip...* **Note that `System.Delegate` is not itself a delegate type**; it is a class type from which all delegate types are derived.

As mentioned by others, it doesn't make a huge amount of sense to do this anyway. Whatever you do, and however you generify this, you have no way of specifying the *arity* (how many parameters to pass), so you would not be able to call it.

Your best bet is to use `Action<T>` or `EventHandler<TEventArgs>`, that way you at least know the number of parameters, and can use generics for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

How will you rise the event? You don't know if the delegate requires arguments and how many and of which type. I would use classes `AEvent`, `AEvent<T>`, `AEvent<T1,T2>` etc. and declare the events using `Action`, `Action<T>` and `Action<T1,T2>` respecitvely.

```cs
public class AEvent
{
    private event Action eventData;
}

public class AEvent<T>
{
    private event Action<T> eventData;
}

public class AEvent<T1, T2>
{
    private event Action<T1, T2> eventData;
}

...
```